# Как добавить свою UWP-программу в контекстное меню Windows?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, меню

Нужно чтобы при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши на папке в всплывающем контекстном меню было и моё UWP-приложение.

[image: Контекстное меню по клику правой кнопки мыши]

И второе как внутри UWP-приложения узнать на какой папке был произведен клик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете связать определенный тип файлов с вашим приложением. Прочитать о том как это можно сделать вы можете здесь: [Обработка активации файла](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation)

О возможности открыть через универсальное приложение через контекстное меню на файле и про открытие папок не слышал. Думаю, что сейчас такого нет.